# DBSCAN homogeneity_score Metrics shows error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am using dbscan to cluster my data.

However, when trying to evaluate the performance using homogeneity_score, it does not show me the metric. I wonder what the issue is. Also, do I need to scale prior to applying dbscan?

```
data = np.array([[-37.530, 3.109 ],
                [40.247, 5.483],
                [-31.920, 12.584]])

#DBSCAN
model = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=10)
model.fit_predict(data)
pred = model.fit_predict(data)


print("homogenity: {}".metrics.homogeneity_score(data,fit_model.labels_))

Out:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'metrics'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `print("homogenity: {}".metrics.homogeneity_score(data,fit_model.labels_))`
to:

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import homogeneity_score
print("%.6f" % homogeneity_score(data, pred))
```

the error is from `fit_model.labels_`, you are giving a string to the score function which does not work, you have to give the predicted values.